Debugger for Python C extension using Jupyter notebooks
Are there any good debuggers specifically for Jupyter Notebooks?
I'm building a C extension for python, it implements a well established algorithm that operates on a set of arrays to produce a single output array, which can have either 1 or 2 dimensions.
Currently my code is stable when I use a basic .py script to test it, even repeating the operation 1000 times. But I run into segmentation faults/memory errors when I use Jupyter notebooks (where I expect most people to want to use this module), or in the python terminal, it randomly crashes. The crash seems to only happen after I call a function from my C module multiple times, but the number of times it needs to be called to generate the crash varies. In the terminal the crash is either accompanied by a free invalid pointer or malloc ... error message.
The module is large, around 2000 lines of code and despite my best efforts, I haven't (yet) been able to reproduce the error in any minimal code example- basically I only get the error in a "complete" piece of code.
So I'm looking for a good debugger to see where the issue lies, also any resources that detail the way in which memory is allocated/dealocated would be helpful.
I've tried adding printf statements throughout the code to isolate when the errors occured in the code, which let me fix some issues, but others still persist.
I have tried isolating components in different files and to opposite, trying to keep everything in the same file.
I've tried swapping calls to malloc for PyDataMem_NEW nothing seems to work.

Can you write a purely C wrapper that calls your function multiple times and check if that also fails?

Look here and here

@MattPitkin I'll do that to double check, although I've checked over that enough that I highly doubt its a problem, also based on when things fail in the python code.

@ImanAbdollahzadeh If I'm not mistaken those are Python level debuggers, I need to profile the C level operations that are occurring during the function call to my C module.

I know only cygdb for that

@MattPitkin Thanks, indeed, my first problem was where I had tinkered with one side piece of code in the underlying C algorithm that resulted in an overflow.


Are there any good [C-level] debuggers specifically for Jupyter Notebooks?

There's no existing tool for this situation. There are debuggers that integrate nicely with Jupyter. There are debuggers that can debug C calls made by Python. There is not, to my knowledge, any debugger which does both.
Valgrind

In the terminal the crash is either accompanied by a free invalid pointer or malloc ... error message.

The first message suggests to me that you are freeing a pointer which was not given to you by malloc. (Or that the pointer is being corrupted somehow.) The second message suggests to me that you are corrupting metadata about an allocation, which the memory allocator usually puts right before the allocation.
Both of those things are something that Valgrind can detect. In order to run this under valgrind, you'd need to run valgrid <command you use to start jupyter notebook>. However, there is a complication: the process you want to trace is a child of the notebook process. To trace children, you will need to use the --trace-children=yes option. See also.
Be aware that Jupyter will be much slower, as Valgrind needs to track every memory access being made. You'll also see some false positives, as not all of the errors will be related to your module.
You might also want to try running your code as a separate .py file under Valgrind. It might be able to detect a memory error that does not crash your program.
GDB
GDB can also work in this situation, and it's a little more flexible, because it can attach to an existing process.
You can find a process ID of your notebook with the following Python:
import os
os.getpid()

You can attach to the process in GDB using this terminal command:
gdb -p PID

where PID is the process ID you found before.
You may find the command break malloc_error_break to be helpful. This will let you get a C stack trace of where your program is crashing, if it is crashing inside malloc.
However, this has a problem: the malloc call where your program is crashing is probably not the cause of your problem. As I mention before, you are probably writing past the end or before the beginning of some buffer, which causes the next call to malloc to fail. You are looking for some incorrect memory usage before this point.

I've tried swapping calls to malloc for PyDataMem_NEW nothing seems to work.

That seems unlikely to matter either way, as PyDataMem_NEW is essentially just calling malloc and optionally tracking memory usage. See the NumPy source code.
